# IOS navigationController pushViewController very slow in first time

Tags: ios, interface, uinavigationcontroller

When I use pushViewController in first time, the speed is very slow (interface suspended animation), it is the normal speed in Second times.

A controller:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      B *b = [[B alloc] init];//xib which the content is very less
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:b animated:YES];
     [b release];
     NSLog(@"yes\n");
}
```

B controller:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   //i have deleted all code
}
//-(void)viewWillAppear.....
```

Main:

```
//https://github.com/ipup/PPRevealSideViewController
A* a = [[A alloc] init];
UINavigationController* n = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:a];
PPRevealSideViewController*  revealSideViewController = [[PPRevealSideViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:n];
//tabbar add revealSideViewController
```

Who knows what is going on?

Comment: its nearly impossible to get the problem out of this lines of code. perhaps something with the xib file or is there any other code in viewDidAppear or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have fixed it ,my xib file has 800k,i also do not know how to make it.

```
<object class="NSColor" key="IBUINormalTitleColor">
 <int key="NSColorSpace">1</int> 
     <bytes>.................
</object>
```

Comment: set UILable(control) background color = (view flipside background color) will create a lot of bytes.